# django overriding default error message in model form or field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Change Every field message is redundancy, so I make the new wrapper

```
class CharFieldWrapper(forms.CharField):     

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CharFieldWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        self.error_messages = {'required' : 'XXXX: YOU SHOULD PUT SOMETHING!' }
```

Yeah, This does not work.

Is anybody knows how make wrapper class of field or form to change error_messages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass them as parameter:

```
class CharFieldWrapper(forms.CharField):

   def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
       kwargs['error_messages'] = {'required' : 'XXXX: YOU SHOULD PUT SOMETHING!' }
       super(CharFieldWrapper, self).init(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your `init` method:

```
class CharFieldWrapper(forms.CharField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CharFieldWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_messages['required'] = 'XXXX: YOU SHOULD PUT SOMETHING!'
```

Also while doing `self.error_messages = {'required': 'my error msg'}` You are completely overwriting `error_messages` which is not good as there might be some other validation errors also. You should update the `self.error_messages` dict not overwrite it as I did.